# rosmake cminpack problem

Tags: ros, md5, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System: OS X 10.6.6 diamondback

When trying to rosmake cminpack (as I try to install perception-pcl again) I get the following error:

```
mkdir -p build
 if [ ! -f cminpack-1.1.1.tar.gz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file cminpack-1.1.1.tar.gz.md5sum" && false; fi
```

There is a cminpack-1.1.1.tar.gz.md5sum file in /cminpack but that wasn't doing it. So I copied it to the build subdirectory and rosmake succeeded. Does that make sense? Here's what Makefile says:

```
VER = 1.1.1
TARBALL       = build/cminpack-$(VER).tar.gz
TARBALL_URL   = http://pr.willowgarage.com/downloads/cminpack-$(VER).tar.gz
UNPACK_CMD    = tar xfz
SOURCE_DIR    = build/cminpack-$(VER)
#TARBALL_PATCH = cminpack.pc.patch
MD5SUM_FILE   = cminpack-$(VER).tar.gz.md5sum
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9272/rosmake-cminpack-problem/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you actually get the error or is is just an echo of that line when executing?

If you're getting that error you will see the line with the if statement and then it will echo it again below.  If you don't see the line twice I expect it is actually executing correctly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-03**:
Hmmm, maybe not. I don't see to be able to reproduce now either.